# Trouble with basic CUDA program. code or compiler?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm taking an online parallel programming course. The homework is done within a virtual machine on their site. My first assignment (below) ran as it should. squaring numbers from 0 to ARRAY_SIZE. When I try to run it on my machine. I get some strange values. I can't find anything wrong with the code. Any suggestions? (output on my machine posted below).

And yes I am aware that my kernel is called cube despite the fact that I am only squaring the number. I just never changed it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void cube( float* d_in, float* d_out ){
int idx = threadIdx.x;
float f = d_in[idx];
d_out[idx] = f*f;
}

int main(){
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 8;
    const int ARRAY_BYTES = ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float);

    // Host memory
    float h_in[ARRAY_SIZE];
    float h_out[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++ )
        h_in[i] = (float)i;

    // Device memory pointers
    float* d_in;
    float* d_out;

    // Allocate device memory
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_in, ARRAY_BYTES );
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_out, ARRAY_BYTES );

    // Transfer input to device
    cudaMemcpy( d_in, h_in, ARRAY_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    // Launch the kernel
    cube<<<1,ARRAY_SIZE>>>(d_out,d_in);

    // Transfer device to host
    cudaMemcpy( h_out, d_out, ARRAY_BYTES, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    printf("%f\n",h_out[i]);



    // Free memory
    cudaFree(d_in);
    cudaFree(d_out);

    return 0;
    }
```

output posted below

```
dan@mojo:~/Dropbox/code/gpu_programming$ nvcc -o first first.cu 
dan@mojo:~/Dropbox/code/gpu_programming$ ./first
-0.000000
-nan
-0.000000
-nan
-0.000000
nan
-nan
-nan
```

Comment: If the same code worked successfully on the remote VM, then you know for a fact that the differences must be due to differences in either the compiler or installed library dependencies on the local machine.

Comment: If you add proper status checking for all CUDA API calls, and all kernel launches, the problem shall reveal itself. In addition you can run your app under the control of cuda-memcheck.

Comment: You should do what @njuffa says.  In addition, your code appears to be broken, in that your kernel is expecting a pointer to the input as the first parameter, but you are passing a pointer to the output as the first parameter when you invoke the kernel.  In other words, when you invoke your kernel, you have your pointer parameters reversed.  So your code does not work for me, and I doubt it could have worked correctly anywhere, as written.

Comment: If you have code which doesn't work and your first instinct is to blame the compile, you will be wrong 99% of the time. 99.99999% of the time if the error arises as part of your course work.

Comment: Wow, that’s embarrassing. Good catch Talonmies and bendorvador, you are correct. I reversed the parameters and of course it worked. I looked back at my submitted homework and realized I had changed a few things at the last minute. One of them being the order of the function parameters.

Comment: Please don't "fix" the code in your question. Your question makes no sense anymore when you remove the problem from your code and you invalidate the answer. Leave it as it is and accept @bendervader 's answer

Comment: You know, not all that long ago, someone else chastised me for not updating my code. So thank you for your help, I mean that, but I'm going to disregard your other comments since certain people on this site seem to think that their personal opinions are written in the code of conduct.

Answer (score 2):

Switch the order of the parameters when launching the kernel, i.e.

```
cube<<<1,ARRAY_SIZE>>>(d_in, d_out);
```